# Alternativa a la traducción "tigresa compacta" en el anime de "Toradora!"

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, adjetivos, japonés, concurso-de-popularidad

Recientemente he visto en Netflix el anime de *Toradora!*, en el que aparece un personaje que, por su fiereza y tamaño, llaman "la tigresa compacta".

[image: Tenori Tiger]

Como el anime está en japonés con subtítulos, oí que en el original decían "tenori taigaa". Reconozco que me tiré toda la serie pensando que "tenori" era como se decía "compacto" en japonés, hasta que finalmente me dio por pensarlo y me di cuenta de que "tenori" es 手乗り, literalmente "que puedes llevar en la mano" o "que se te monta en la mano", de ahí la imagen de arriba (que aparece en la serie). Se escribe usando el *kanji* de "mano" (手) y el de "montarse" o "subirse a" (乗, el que se usa para decir que te has montado en el autobús, por ejemplo).

Poniendo los subtítulos en inglés en Netflix he visto que en ese idioma la llaman "palm-top tiger", que refleja mejor el original. Así pues, pregunta: ¿cuál podría ser una mejor adaptación en español de "tenori taigaa" como "tigresa que puedes llevar en la mano"? ¿Que otro adjetivo o expresión corta podríamos usar en vez de "compacta"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A mi lo primero que se me ocurre es ["de bolsillo"](https://dle.rae.es/bolsillo?m=form)

> 1. loc. adj. Dicho de una cosa: **Que por su hechura y tamaño resulta menor de lo habitual entre las de su especie**.

Así que la "tenori taigaa" habría sido, si yo fuese el encargado de la traducción una **Tigresa de bolsillo**.

Comment: Ganadora por votación popular. :-)

Answer (score 4):

Por lo que refiere tu investigación del significado japonés de origen —en cuanto a que es portable o se lleva en la palma—, también  a este mini animalito le  cabría la denominación de

> tigresa de mano

(Razón por lo cual tal es la traducción elegida para la versión anglosajona: "palm-top tiger")

Vease

> [de mano](https://dle.rae.es/mano?m=form#BzIz9VN)

1. loc. adj. Dicho de una cosa: Que se maneja directamente con las manos, o es portátil o fácil de transportar con ellas. Bomba, escalera, equipaje, programa de mano.

Como curiosidad, agrego que existió una serie también japonesa referida a unos caballos diminutos que (en Argentina) llegó traducida como ["Mi pequeño pony"](https://doblaje.fandom.com/es/wiki/Mi_peque%C3%B1o_pony:_La_serie). Como en Castellano existe la palabra [poni](https://dle.rae.es/poni) ("*caballo de cierta raza o poca alzada*"), en tren de buscar un neologismo también podría haberse pensado en llamarla algo así como

> la *tigresa poni*

o simplemente:

> [mini](https://dle.rae.es/mini-?m=form)-tigresa